# Moving question to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, close-reasons, migration

I saw on MSE a question about an algorithm in C++ for listing combinations of objects. I unfortunately can't provide you the link because the question has been deleted by the user. Since it is specific to a programmation language it was clear to me that the question should be closed as "off-topic" and moved to StackOverflow. However, the only targets proposed were:

meta.math.stackexchange.com

stats.stackexchange.com

physics.stackexchange.com

I can imagine that there is a good reason why we can't choose any StackExchange platform. Relation between maths and informatics can sometimes be very tight, so why Stack Overflow isn't in this list?

Comment: Stack Overflow will probably be added as a migration path if a) we have a non-negligible number of questions migrated there, and b) the users here demonstrate that they have good judgment on such migrations, i.e. don't migrate crap or questions that are off-topic there to SO. For the time being, flagging for moderator attention, "other->belongs to Stack Overflow because ..." is the way to go. If we only migrate three or four questions per year to SO, adding it as a migration path doesn't make much sense even if all migrated questions are good.

Comment: @DanielFischer This makes sense. I edited my question so that, if you want, you can post this comment as an acceptable answer.

Comment: I changed the to "support" as this matches the new version more closely.

Comment: In my experience, most of the programming questions asked on MSE are questions from on-going programming contests.  They ask them here because (I suppose) fewer mathematicians than programmers are familiar with these contests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stack Overflow will probably be added as a migration path if

1. we have a non-negligible number of questions migrated there, and
2. the users here demonstrate that they have good judgment on such migrations, i.e. don't migrate crap or questions that are off-topic there to SO.

For the time being, flagging the question for moderator attention, "other->belongs to Stack Overflow because ..." is the way to go.

If we only migrate three or four questions per year to SO, adding it as a migration path doesn't make much sense even if all migrated questions are good.

Comment: I always thought that mods had better things to do than migrate, so I voted to close (also this particular instance) for "not about mathematics". Perhaps a mod could confirm that such a flag is actually helpful? I imagine flags should only be used if the community can't serve itself here such as pointing the user to the appropriate Q&A-site and closing the question.

Comment: If there is no migration path to the site a question belongs, the only way to migrate it is by letting a moderator migrate it. Of course you should be pretty sure that the question is migratable (on topic on the target and of good quality, also less than 60 days old) before you flag to avoid causing the moderators unnecessary work. Closing the question here and letting the OP re-ask it on the other site would work too in a way, but if you flag, the moderators can confer with the moderators on the putative target to make sure the question is appropriate.

Comment: Time to raise some flags in the near future :) I usually refrain from this since my privileges already allow a great deal of moderation tasks on my own and truly offensive are (luckily) very rare.